# Can you normalize an email address where local-part uses quoted-pair?

Tags: c#, email

Is the email address john.doe@example.com equivalent to "john.doe"@example.com? I've read that you should not modify or normalize the local-part of an email address. Does that included a local-part that is a quoted-pair?

Comment: It's my understanding that those are equal. The local part can be contained by double quotes and that is not a modification of the unquoted local part, just a different syntax.

Comment: They're equal as long as the unquoted form contains only unrestricted ASCII characters. Considering the example (and assuming there's nothing hidden like a HT character that's not rendering), yes they're equal. When they're not equal is when the quoted form contains non-ASCII characters or restricted ASCII characters, in which case the unquoted form is invalid.

Comment: @user1558782: What kind of normalization are you expecting/hoping to be able to do? If you got something quoted, I'd say leave it alone, even if it's valid without the quotes. Don't try to take on that responsibility.

Comment: We have application where users register using email address. We enforce that email address is unique. If there was a user in the system with email address john.doe@example.com, our system would allow another user to register with "john.doe"@example.com. That seems like a problem. We use sendgrid for sending automatic notifications to our users, but depending on email server, if we sent out an email to john.doe@example.com for one user, and "john.doe"@example.com for the other user, those 2 separate emails might end up going to the same box. What do we need to do to prevent this?